# Formatting histograms in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to fit Variance-Gamma distribution to empirical data of 1-minute logarithmic returns. In order to visualize the results I plotted together 2 histograms: empirical and theoretical.
(`a` is the vector of empirical data)

```
SP_hist <- hist(a, 
                col = "lightblue", 
                freq = FALSE, 
                breaks = seq(a, max(a), length.out = 141), 
                border = "white", 
                main = "", 
                xlab = "Value", 
                xlim = c(-0.001, 0.001))

hist(VG_sim_rescaled, 
     freq = FALSE, 
     breaks = seq(min(VG_sim_rescaled), max(VG_sim_rescaled), length.out = 141), 
     xlab = "Value", 
     main = "", 
     col = "orange", 
     add = TRUE)
```

(empirical histogram-blue, theoretical histogram-orange)

[image]

However, after having plotted 2 histograms together, I started wondering about 2 things:

1. In both histograms I stated, that `freq = FALSE`. Therefore, the y-axis should be in range (0, 1). In the actual picture values on the y-axis exceed 3,000. How could it happen? How to solve it?
2. I need to change the bucketing size (the width of the buckets) and the density per unit length of the x-axis. How is it possible to do these tasks?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freq=FALSE` means that the *area* of the entire histogram is normalized to one. As your x-axis has a very small range (about 10^(-4)), the y-values must be quite large to achieve an area (= x times y) of one.

The only way to set the number of bins is by providing a vector of break points to the parameter *breaks*. Theoretically, this parameter also accepts a single number, but this number is ignored by *hist*. Thus try the following:

```
bins <- 6   # number of cells
breaks <- seq(min(x),max(x),(max(x)-min(x))/bins)
hist(x, freq=FALSE, breaks=breaks)
```

Comment: Setting `breaks` to a number isn't ignored by `hist()`, but the value is taken only as a suggestion. So `breaks = 100` will give you lots of bins, `breaks = 3` won't give many.  `hist()` uses `pretty()` to choose the actual bins based on the suggested number, with a preference for round number boundaries.

Comment: @cdaliztz  **freq=FALSE means that the area of the entire histogram is normalized to one. As your x-axis has a very small range (about 10^(-4)), the y-values must be quite large to achieve an area 
(= x times y) of one.**

And is it possible to change it anyhow?

Comment: @Maxim: "And is it possible to change it anyhow?" The idea is that the histogram is an approximation of a probability densirty by a step function. The normalization to area One thus makes perfect sense. You can normalize it to any value you like by multiplying the values avlues in hist$density by some scale factor (assign the reuslt to a variable and set plot=FALSE).